# nodejs- unable to fetch form data

Tags: node.js, express

I'm using Express JS (v 4.15.3) for building a node api.

I'm trying to fetch the values send from a form (via POSTman client). I'm not able to fetch it.

This is my form

**with headers specified**

[image]

**Without headers**

[image]

This is how I'm trying to fetch it:

```
router.post('/login',function(req, res, next) {
    var email= req.body.email;
    //var email= req.query.email; //also tried this
    res.json({
      value: email
    });
});
```

I'm not getting error.

Note: I have included body parser.

```
var bodyParser = require('body-parser'); 
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
```

Can anyone tell me why I am not getting the value? Thanks!
This is my first attempt at learning Node JS.

Comment: Have you tried `application/json` as Content-Type?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code seems perfectly alright. Though the issue is with the way you are sending request from POSTman client.

When you are sending request using **use form data**, POSTman sends this request as **multipart/form-data**, which actually sends your data in the format as below:

```
POST /api/login HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:3000
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Cache-Control: no-cache

----WebKitFormBoundaryE19zNvXGzXaLvS5C
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="email"

example@example.com
----WebKitFormBoundaryE19zNvXGzXaLvS5C
```

For **multipart/form-data** requests you need to use **multer** middleware, if you really need file-uploads with your application. But for your case you can just send data without using **use form data** (un-check the *use form data* checkbox), and setting content-type header as:

```
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
```

So after all these modifications your *raw web request* should look something like below:

```
POST /api/login HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:3000
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Cache-Control: no-cache

email=example@example.com
```

The POSTman screen capture for building the request and response is as below:

[image: POSTman screen capture for building the request and response]

The POSTman screen capture for **Raw** request  and response is as below:

[image: POSTman screen capture for Raw request and response]

Hope this will help you.

Answer (score 0):

Try to set Content-Type to application/json and in body in raw write in json format like this :

```
{
    "email":"example@gmail.com"
}
```

Here are the images which you can refer.

[image]

[image]

Don't forget to upvote the answer if you find it helpful.